# I want links like index/anotherpage in html webpages

Tags: html, css

Suppose I have a file called **Index.html** and another file called **another.html** , when I click `another.html` in `Index.html` I want header like this `Index.html/Another.html` , is it possible ?

Comment: what do you mean by header?

Comment: You cannot do that using HTML only.

Comment: use a restful framework.. If you use php, try codeIgniter... You will be able to make the url look as you want.

Comment: Thank you , i am gonna try it , and header = url :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you think of a navbar you can copy paste it from index.html to another.html or use a frgmantation strategy which would avoid having the same code on multiple places.

If you are talking about the URL you can specify this in the header with the title tag:

```
<title>index/another.html</title>
```

But it would be bad style to say index.html/another.html instead use index/another.html